# Accommodate custom item on winrt listview

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm developing windows metro app. In my application, I've one Listview with wrapgrid in itemspanel to display list of items on vertical rows with specific height. I want to display one item on top of the first column of list view, which shows result/stats of list items.
I would like to know if it is possible without adding custom item to datasource of listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, I've implemented following solution which is not elegant but worked for me.

1. Use Datasource converter to add dummy item in main list. So, my original list remains as is.
2. Use Template Selector to bind different template for first item.
3. Handle Selection and clicked event of dummy item.

Answer (score 0):

ListView has a [Header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.header.aspx) property in which you can Place content before the ListViews Items.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it will not work in my case as **Header** will occupy the whole row or column based on orientation defined in your WrapPanel (Vertical in my case). All I want is to have only first item of first column to be different.

Comment: Ok, then i recommend using the DataTemplateSelector to just give a different appearence to the first item (and add a dummy in the first spot of your data source).

Comment: Yes, I am in a process to use same approach which is not elegant. But it seems, WinRT does not left us with an either option.